# Reputation transaction screen: show bonuses & reductions due to deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation

During the brouhaha over the account association bonus, I noticed that the bonuses do not show up in the "Recent Activity" screen, nor do they (apparently) show up in the user reputation screen.  Apparently, there are other reasons why rep can change stealthily.

I **knew** my Server Fault rep had dropped over the weekend, but could not for the life of me figure out why!

This is a problem.  When rep is added or removed, a transaction should be shown.  A transaction should not be **removed**, it should be **reversed** with an offsetting transaction.  We all may be anal, but we do keep track, at least approximately!

What do you all think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this question was asked, this feature was not available, but it is now. Details on how it works are available at [the FAQ entry for the reputation log](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614/131713).

Answer (score 1):

The recent activity screen does a halfway decent of of keeping track of you rep gains and losses over the time periods. I would much rather see that page modified to take into account things like special bonuses or losses due to deleted answers and questions then I would rather see a completely different screen try and do a better job. No point in having two areas where one does it half-decent and the other tries to plug other holes. Just plug the holes in the Recent Activity.

Comment: Agreed .. I presume the least disruptive fix is to add the deletion of a question and other currently silent rep changes to the existing screens.