# How do I read the history of my reputation?

Tags: support, faq, reputation, reputation-history

When I visit the reputation tab of my profile, I see a lot of stuff. I can make out some of it, but not all.

- What do all the event types mean?
- Why do some events show an odd reputation gain or not show any reputation change at all?
- Why are some events sometimes highlighted in yellow?
- My reputation suddenly dropped, but I don't see anything. What happened?
- Why do some events disappear from my reputation history?

[Return to FAQ Index](/q/7931)

Comment: Would this be the place to explain about the reputation history available also at `/reputation` and the [graphs in the network profiles?](http://stackexchange.com/users/268952/lix?tab=reputation)

Comment: @Lix: I suppose it could be relevant, but I'm not sure what exactly to explain concerning either of those.

Comment: @ani - Main thing I think would be the network reputation charts. That you can see roughly how much reputation you had at a certain date. It also shows all the sites together...

Comment: @Lix It would certainly be a place to mention it, so that a user like me who had seen it once and forgotten where to get it would find out that http://stackoverflow.com/reputation is where to go if you want a single page of text listing post numbers in chronological order, separated by dates, showing the rep change associated with that post at that time, so thanks!

Answer (score 38):

### What are all the event types and what do they mean?

- **upvote** / **downvote** - Your post was upvoted or downvoted.
- **unupvote** / **undownvote** - An upvote or downvote previously cast on the post was retracted.
- **downvoted** - Note the extra "d" at the end; you cast a downvote on an answer. Downvotes you cast on questions are not shown in your reputation history and do not affect your reputation.
- **accept** / **unaccept** - Your answer was accepted or unaccepted by the OP, or you accepted an answer on one of your questions.
- **bounty** - You offered a bounty on a question or a bounty was awarded on your answer.
- **removed** - Has 2 different uses:

  1. *When a post is linked or shown as plain text:* A post was deleted (this could be a post of yours or a post you took specific moderation actions on). Keep in mind that when a question is deleted, all of its answers are automatically deleted as well, so your own post or the post you took moderation actions on may be an answer to a deleted post. *When a post gets deleted, the question's title will be shown in plain text unless you are able to view the deleted post (10K users or the question owner).*

     - For posts that are your own, the reputation change reflects the reputation you lost/gained through upvotes and downvotes to your post.
     - For posts that are *not* your own, the reputation change reflects any reputation you earned or lost for moderating that post.  Moderation actions which affect reputation include downvoting an answer or suggesting an edit.
  2. When [*User was removed*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470) is shown: When a user is removed, all reputation gained from suggested edits on which they cast the final or binding vote to approve will be revoked, and in most cases, all of their votes on posts are invalidated. The change in reputation reflects the reputation gained or lost according to that user's votes on your posts and any of your suggested edits they approved. Note that if multiple users are removed on the same day, all removal events will be combined into a single event, and if there are also one or more events of type *reversal* (see below) on a day a user was removed, those will be combined into a single *removed* event as well.
- **migrated** - Your post was migrated to another site.
- **edit** - An edit you suggested to a post or tag wiki was approved.
- **reversal** - Another user's votes on one or more of your posts [were reversed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829).(Displayed as ["Voting corrected"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252025/165773).) If there are multiple events of this type on a single day, those will be combined into a single event, and if one or more events of type *User was removed* (see above) occur on the same day, reversal events will be combined into that as well.
- **reverted** - One of your approved suggested edits was later overridden and rejected by a moderator or the post owner.
- **assoc** - You have at least 200 reputation on at least 1 site, so you were automatically granted 100 reputation as a one-time bonus.

---

### Why is there an unexpected or no reputation change next to the event?

Most often it's due to you hitting the reputation cap. You can only earn up to 200 reputation from votes and edits in a single day. Sometimes the last event that puts you up to the limit will be slightly less than what you'd normally find, such as a +6 for an upvote to your answer. After hitting the cap, all additional events will show no reputation change.

Additionally, any upvotes you get to community wiki questions or answers you have will still show up in the reputation history, but will not show any reputation change next to them since they are not eligible for reputation gain.

Events in your reputation history are also wrapped up into a single line when they occur on the same day. If you are viewing your history by time, this can cause some confusion as it might appear that you have received additional reputation for a new upvote that just occurred, when in fact you didn't. See:

[image: +70, 0, +10]

This is because that single post will be listed by the time of the *last* event on your post with the sum of *all* events on that post, even if you didn't gain any additional reputation for that event. If you find this confusing, try switching your reputation history view to the post option. This will allow you to expand each post to see all the separate events for it, including how many gained you reputation and how many didn't.

[image: View history by post]

---

### Why are events sometimes separated from other related events?

*In other words, why are there sometimes two entries for votes on the same post, with one showing earlier changes and another showing later changes?*

New events that you haven't seen yet regarding your reputation will be separated and shown on the top of the list. They will only be separated for that single view of the page; if you leave and return to your reputation history, they will be combined. The total amount of the separated events should add up to the number in the blue bubble of the reputation tab itself (excluding any **removed** and **reversal** events). The blue bubble is meant to indicate the total amount your reputation has changed since you last checked the reputation tab; it will continue to appear until you've visited the tab at least once.

---

### My reputation dropped, but I don't see anything listed!

This can be caused by one of several different reasons:

- **Removed posts are hidden by default.** More than likely, you don't have your reputation history set to show removed posts. By default, removed posts are hidden from the history pages. In order to show removed posts, you need to make sure the checkbox all the way at the bottom is checked.

  [image: Show removed posts]
- **Reversal events from the same day.** When you receive an upvote and a subsequent unupvote event (or an accept and an unaccept, or a downvote and an undownvote) from the same user on the same day, the events collapse into each other and are not displayed in your reputation history. This was primarily done to prevent users from spamming a user's reputation history with consistent events reversing each other. A reversed event (unupvote, undownvote, unaccept) will only appear if it occurs on a day other than the day the original event occurred.
- **Background processes.** If you're still unable to see what caused a sudden reputation drop, there may have been a system process in the background. This usually happens when two or more accounts are merged together.

---

### Why would an event disappear from my reputation history?

This *should* only occur for upvotes, downvotes, and accepts. Whenever one of these actions gets reversed during the same day, the event is just completely removed from your history rather than creating a separate unupvote, undownvote, or unaccept event in the list. This was done to prevent users clicking a vote on/off repeatedly to fill up a user's history with useless events.

Comment: What about when a post is deleted as spam/rude?