# Lost reputation, but the decrease does not show in my reputation history

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

I had a total of 308 rep, which now is reduced to 288. I checked the rep history and saw no indication of any reputation being lost. Of course, I would like to know how it was lost so I can avoid losing it in the future. Is there a way to find out what action caused the decrease?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the bottom of your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957407/tehdoommarine?tab=reputation&sort=post), and check the checkbox you find there:

[image: show removed posts checkbox]

then check your reputation list again once the page has reloaded. The 20 point loss is probably due to a deleted post; perhaps a question you answered was deleted.

Comment: Yes, they had an answer with two upvotes on a question that was deleted yesterday. Thus the 20 point loss.

Comment: I regret that this question/answer has been closed, because I have found my solution here more quickly than reading too big article indicated in closure post ! It is also regrettable that "Show Removed Posts" is not checked by default or replaced by "hide removed posts" unchecked. It is also regrettable that this CheckBox is displayed at bottom of page and not in header or top of page !