# Why my reputation dropped without showing reason in the reputation tab?

Tags: support, reputation

On August 21, I had a reputation of **2529** in stackoverflow, and after some time, it dropped to **2527**. I thought it as a -1 to my answer. But the reputation tab is not showing anything.
[image: Reputation]

What will be the possible reason for this?

EDIT

I enabled "show removed posts" option and the complete screenshot is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzZtF.png

Comment: Did you turn on "show removed posts" at the very bottom of your reputation list? A post for which you suggested an edit might have been removed.

Comment: See [Lost reputation, but the decrease does not show in my reputation history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144631/). One option is that post you edited (with a suggested edit) was deleted, that'd be a -2.

Comment: I did it. here is the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/32qOX.png

Comment: You can always visit http://stackoverflow.com/reputation to trigger a re-calc and do a full audit. Also, though I am not certain, if an suggested edit was approved for a post and the post was subsequently deleted within the grace period, it *could* be that the removal event is not shown on your reputation tab, you just loose the 2 points again. Compare to a `accept` then `unaccept` event close together, which are also removed from your history.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it shows "rep today: 20". I know about 20, 2 upvotes for my answers, but still I don't know about -2