# Reputation gain showing after reaching 200 for the day?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-history

I've already reached the limit of 200 reputation for the day and even got the modified +4 reputation for an upvote. After that, I got a couple events which gained me no reputation, then suddenly a +10 again. Why did this happen?

> [image: See the +10 above no-rep-gain events]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reputation tab collapses all the votes into one line, and the total reputation you earned for that question is shown on the most recent vote for the answer.

If you add up all the vote scores on your listing, it'll still only add up to 200.

For the top-most listed answer, I received 60 points from upvotes, but the most recent upvote was well beyond my 200 point cap for today:

[image: rep-cap hit already, yet 60 points listed]

At the time of that screenshot, I had received my 9th upvote.

Comment: I've added this to the FAQ: [How do I read the history of my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)