# Can someone please explain what this "removed" entry means in my rep history

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

I downvoted [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148894/135956) and a few hours later, can see the following in my rep history (when `Show removed posts` is enabled)...

```
+1   17:25  removed What's the demonym for people who use Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow?
-1   16:46  downvoted   What's the demonym for people who use Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow?
```

I didn't un-downvote and the question is still active. Can someone please explain what the `removed` entry relates to? The question is still active but locked so I can't re-downvote...

Any explanation greatly appreciated. Clearly this is a mechanism I'm not familiar with.

Comment: You downvoted a post and that post is now deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is still active, but there were several answers by the OP on that post that have been deleted.  It appears you must have downvoted one of those.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Presumably if I had 10k I'd be able to see what I'd downvoted, I'll accept ASAP