# Reputation adjustment?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

This morning my reputation went over the 20k, yay ...

It was at 20018 when I went out and by the time I came back it was reduced to 19953, a 65 points reduction; however, there's no record of that in the reputation overview.

Is there a tax system I wasn't aware of? :)

Comment: Did you enable "show removed posts" at the very bottom of your reputation list?

Comment: @Bart doh! you're absolutely right :) I didn't see it until I scrolled all the way down.

Comment: :) No problem. Common issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. Jon Skeet has been complaining about it forever now...

Seriously though, chances are that an upvoted post of yours got deleted and the associated reputation has gone with it.

In your reputation page, at the bottom, there is a checkbox "show removed posts" - this will display any removed posts and show you how much reputation went with any such post.

Also see [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)