# Why does the rep log show upvotes with no rep seemingly before the 200 rep limit?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

Here's an example [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=time):

[image]

See those three upvotes that are disconnected from the ones near the bottom? Why are they disconnected?

In other words, why don't the last 30 rep points result from the questions "In C#, should...", "What is the exa..." and "can we get the..."?

Clarification: 3 hours ago did this list look as follows?

[image]

That only has 170 total rep, and a bunch of upvotes with no rep. Or is the "time ago" field completely misleading and doesn't mean what I think it means?

Comment: [Happy now](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=post)? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not really :) Does this list change over time or something? 3 hours ago, all of those "blank" upvotes weren't there. Did the list show 170 or 200 total rep? If 170, why didn't the last three upvotes count?

Comment: No worry I was just joking, going to post real answer now.

Comment: Hmm, already noon, and Mr. Skeet has not yet a single accept? Something's wrong on the intarnets. Edit: Ah, he just got one. Sanity restored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time-sorted reputation page shows the total rep earned for each question upvoted. So the ones near the top were more recently upvoted than others below them, but *at some point* they were upvoted before the rep-cap was hit.

In other words, the [`using LINQ` answer was upvoted 4 times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/853526/timeline) today, and only the 1st time did Jon receive 10 points for it. The other 3 votes were received after he had hit the rep cap, and the last time this happend was 8 minutes before your screenshot.

You can see this much better in the [per-post sorting of Jon's reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=post):

[image: per-post score for the LINQ answer]

The per-post tab gives you much better information as to what votes were given per post.

Comment: This does not seem to apply to the answer for a question titled "using LINQ to remove objects within a List<T>" - it only got upvoted once today, and Jon got rep for it 35 minutes ago.

Comment: @romkyns: it was upvoted 4 times today, see the link I included.

Comment: Ooooh...... so the time shown *is* misleading.

Comment: Exactly, it only shows the most recent upvote there.

Comment: It should really show the time of the *first* upvote each day then... Too minor to warrant a fix request?

Comment: I'd say too minor. It has never bothered me in any case, I certainly also want to know when the most recent upvote occurred myself. The rep display tries to be concise and collapses upvotes, if you want all the detail use the per-post tab instead.