# Answer Upvotes only 5 Points?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Upvotes for my answers have always brought me 10 points. But over the past couple of days, it looks like they're only bringing me 5 points.

Did something change?

Comment: You might also be interested in [How do I read the history of my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation).

Comment: I hardly think the mentioned question is an exact duplicate! In fact, I know how Reputation works. But was just unable to correctly interpret what I was seeing in this case.

Comment: @JonathanWood - The answer for that community FAQ fully answers your question... that's why it got marked as duplicate :)

Answer (score 6):

You hit the reputation cap of 200 a day.

You had 195 reputation from upvotes, then the answer got upvoted - you got the 5 to take you to 200.

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Ah, that must be it. I thought I was getting several +5s but, after checking, I see some of them were in fact questions. So that explains why I haven't seen more points today from my other answers. Thanks.