# What "please delete; rescinded" means in the reputation tab?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

I've just seen -20 in [my reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569101/j0k?tab=reputation) with label *please delete; rescinded*.

[image]

What does it mean? Is it about a question where a user asked to remove it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you posted an answer, that had gotten two upvotes, to a question whose author later retitled it to "(please delete; rescinded)". The question was then deleted, and your answer with it, so you have lost the rep from those upvotes.

Since there's no way to search for deleted questions, that's all we can tell from this entry; you'll probably have to wait for a moderator if you need more information.

Comment: Oooh ok, this is the question title. I thought it was a generic message.

Comment: @j0k: If you had 10,000 reputation, it would be a link to the question and you can easily figure these things out yourself. :) It's plain-text for those without the privilege to view it. Although, if I knew the URL, I would edit it to re-instate the actual title. Changing it to "please delete" is completely inappropriate.

Comment: Rolled back question - title now appears sane.