# Is it possible to be awarded with +1 rep in some cases?

Tags: support

I am curious about the +1 rep I was awarded for a "removed" question (Not mine). I couldn't find any case where only 1 rep was involved.

Yesterday, I got this in my reputation tab:

> +1     12:21   removed     Remove the suffix in urls

Although the message does not have a link, I searched in Google and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345492/remove-the-suffix-in-urls), that was indeed answered by me.

But that question is still active and I am not even sure it is the question the message is referring to.

Does anybody have an idea of the reason for that reputation point?

Comment: Meta has been getting *way* too many "why does my history say +/- *x* reputation?" questions lately... -- [How do I read the history of my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

Comment: @animuson Thought so but couldn't find anything similar. I have to improve my search skills here, though. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my guess:

- You downvoted the answer by Rachel Gallen. (-1)
- Rachel deletes [her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345560/922184) (10k link).
- You are refunded that 1 rep. (+1)

You are seeing that +1 in your reputation history.

Comment: That is why the entry says, "removed."

Comment: Yes. That seems the correct explanation. I can't see the deleted answers but maybe I did down vote one of them. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I thought it was impossible to identify a specific down-vote by someone else. How were you able to pin this downvote to a specific answer?

Comment: @GangDownvoted Because I hacked into the database. MUAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!

Comment: The OP actually gave it away in the question. The +1 indicates that something he downvoted was deleted. The name of the question was there as well. So I went to the question and there's only one downvote on all the answers. (it was on the deleted answer)

Comment: @Mysticial: That makes sense; thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you've downvote a post, you lose 1 rep, when that post gets deleted, you get that rep back