# Missing entry in the reputation tab based on the sort type

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, reputation-history

An upvote entry for one of my answers seems to be missing from the reputation tab, when sorted based upon *time*. But the very same entry seems to be visible when I view the reputation tab sorted based upon the *post*. Below are the snapshots to explain it more clearly.

*Case 1: Sorted based upon post*

[image: Visible entry]

*Case 2: Sorted based upon time*

[image: Not visible entry]

So is this behavior a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

*Note:* I'm not asking why I didn't get the *10 rep* because I know that I've already hit the daily rep-cap. Rather I'm asking about the missing blank upvote entry which I got after hitting the rep-cap. Also, there might be a 2-3 min time gap between the entries in the 2 snapshots as I took the second screenshot after 2-3 mins.

Comment: Downvoter, this is not regarding me hitting the daily rep-cap. I know that upvotes post the rep-cap yield no rep, but the problem here is that an entry itself is missing. Please read the question fully. I clearly mentioned a note so that nobody gets confused with rep-cap problem. Thus, its not a duplicate either.

Comment: I think the -1 here is because it might be seen as too minor and edge case. +1 from me though, if only for sheer curiosity. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I really doubt if this would be an edge-case, as many users hit the rep-cap daily. And also, the sorting type shouldn't really make any difference in the entries which are to be shown. It may be a bit minor, but then, its something which is not going out of my head! :)

Comment: @hims056 - I doubt if the linked question is a duplicate. The missing entry explanation given there is for vote reversals within a day, whereas in my case, nothing of that sort has happened.

Comment: @R.J - Read the last two paragraphs under "Why is there an unexpected or no reputation change next to the event?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting by time will show [the latest time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139615/187824) per action with the sum of all actions on that post(i.e. accept, upvote, downvote, etc.). In other words: for any post there will be only one entry with sum of all reputation (latest time) for any action. E.g. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19948928/1369235) has 6 upvotes and an acceptance and no downvotes. So it will show you two entries for that (+60 and +15) with latest time.

Same happened with your [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951532/how-to-check-for-a-duplicate-string-using-regex-in-java/19951629#19951629). It has upvotes and a downvote and it is not accepted. So it shows you two entry with latest time. So sorting by time I can see that first you got a downvote (-2 rep) then an upvote (+2 rep) then again an upvote(0 rep). So it shows sum of all downvotes (-2) and upvote (+2) with latest time of particular action.

So it's by design.

Comment: Look at the first snapshot. The order was *-2*, *+2* and then 0 rep upvote. And I'm sure about this, as I was monitoring that post myself where I saw the downvote first, and then the 2 upvotes were cast.

Comment: @R.J - Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Ah now it makes sense. I had directly jumped to the section where it said missing entry, so thought that my answer might be there. Also, you re-ordering(by mistake) the events got me into a deeper confusion. Thanks for clarifying it so well! :)