# Why does the reputation tab displays +1 or +3 for upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Some days ago in Reputation Tab of some users profile I saw some strange reputation changes like:

**+1 Upvote:**
[image: +1 Upvote]

**+3 Upvote:**
[image: +3 Upvote]

For upvotes usually one will get +10. If they get down-votes it's also included in the reputation tab. But what is this +1 upvote and +3 upvote? Is that a bug?

Comment: There is a reputation cap; hit it and you don't get any more points. But downvoting costs reputation placing you slightly *under* the cap, so the next upvote only gives you enough points to be capped again.

Comment: In other words, no this is not a bug.

Comment: Also see [How do I read the history of my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614)