# 492+10=500 points?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

Forgive me if I'm missing something. Today I encountered something strange on Stackoverflow. Yesterday I was at 492 points, today I answered a question & got an upvote(+10) & reached 500(yay!). But technically my points should have been 502 but its still 500. I looked at my time-wise reputation,there are no downvotes.

My notification also just showed +8(sorry can't provide the screenshot as I clicked on it). Now the recent achievements tab is also saying +10 for my last answer ?

Could someone please explain ?

Comment: Perhaps you gave two downvotes :) each one costs 1 rep.. and mystery solved?

Comment: my whole activity today is 2 comments & 1 answer :P

Comment: Removed posts are hidden; check the 'show removed posts' checkbox and see if a post you suggested an edit for was deleted. See [How do I read the history of my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yesterday two were deleted,yes..(thanks,didnt knew about that) but today its just one accept.

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: hey thanks!!(one more new thing ;))
& yes it was my mistake then.. :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: you were right,thnxxx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A post was probably deleted. Scroll down in your reputation tab and check the checkbox "show removed posts."

Perhaps a post that you suggested an edit on was deleted, or an answer with +1/-4, or a question with +2/-4.

This would also explain the +8 in the rep tab, since negative rep events aren't shown there but still count towards the number shown.

Comment: like i just said  yesterday two were deleted,yes..(thanks,didnt knew about that) but today its just one accept.& i did check my points today in the morning

Comment: @stevieG The only thing we can conclude is that you're misremembering what you had and hadn't seen. Your reputation is correct.

Comment: @animuson: Hehe...yeah humans make mistakes,machines don't....

Comment: @stevieG in all the movies/books where machines take over the world/universe, they end up doing enough mistakes to lose. :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizard: or maybe that's what they want us to believe(in grim voice)... :P

Comment: @stevieG so you're saying we live inside the Matrix? ;)

Comment: Or maybe we are the Matrix......:P