# Reputation not getting added after awarded Copy Editor badge

Tags: support, reputation, edits

Yesterday, I was awarded the golden badge **Copy Editor** in Stack Overflow. After it, I edited some more posts but even they were accepted by the user, I didn't get any reputations. Today for one of my question, I accepted an answer for which it was shown 2 reputation is awarded. But my reputation still remains the same.

Why this is happening? Is my account blocked from anything?

Comment: You've hit the +1000 reputation cap for suggested edits.

Answer (score 3):

Reputation gained from suggested edits is capped at 1 000. Every suggested edit is +2 and Copy Editor requires 500 edits. 500*2 = 1 000. You reached the cap, congratulations!

Comment: Yep I was awarded Copy Editor when I completed 500 edits, but is there limitation for editing posts?

Comment: @Jenz There are [some limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), but they only affect how often you can edit, not how many times.

Comment: then why even if my edits are approved my reputation is not getting increased. Even with the case of accepting an answer ( 2 reputation).

Comment: @Jenz You only get +2 rep from the first 500 approved suggested edits. Not getting reputation from accepting an answer can be caused by accepting your own answer, other than that I can't be sure without investigating.

Comment: We are awarded with reputation of 2 when we have accepted a user's answer for our question. Right? In my account it is showing 2 reputation for that. But reputation still remains the same.

Comment: @Jenz Correct, but I don't know why your reputation would stay the same. I don't have time to further dig into your reputation history, though. You could check http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: okay thanks @3ventic...

Comment: @Jenz: Your reputation *did* go up by +2 for an accepted answer. Do check for deleted posts though; if a post you edited was deleted, you lost the +2 from that suggested edit again. Check the 'show removed posts' box at the bottom of your reputation tab to check; see [How do I read the history of my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614)