# How do I get a complete list of reputation changes for all sites at once?

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

I try to get access to the reputation changes for all sites to program an Add-on, that displays them.

The achievement notification list at the top shows the last reputation changes in a list, but how can I get this list separately?

Is there a secret link?

The link to global reputation changes only shows a chart:
https://stackexchange.com/users/1047481/rubo77?tab=reputation

In case, there is no such list how is the achievement list generated?

Comment: Here you can see how to read it for one site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation

Comment: If you want the raw data the top bar is using, you have [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/topbar/achievements). You'll have to parse it yourself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: +1 !!! that is exactly the question. please convert this to an answer

Comment: Your Wish is My Command!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean only the recent changes, exactly as seen in the top bar, then you can read its raw feed.

That feed is accessible via a "secret" URL indeed: https://stackexchange.com/topbar/achievements

It's a raw view only and you'll have to parse it yourself.

Comment: All links look the same, I think the link that always wors is http://stackexchange.com/topbar/achievements

Comment: Wow, what a blonde moment on my side! Correct, I've edited the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different places.

First the not-secret-at-all:

Go to your profile page, on any Q&A site. Click the reputation tab under the account summary:

> [image: reputation tab]

The somewhat-secret-but-known-to-old-hands:

Go to the reputation audit page on the site. Simply patch on `/reputation` to the site base address:

```
http://<site-url>/reputation
```

---

There is no place to see a full list of reputation changes from across the network.

Comment: that is not the global list, its only for one site, please re-read my question

Comment: Well, that little edit changes things significantly... However, there is no such list.

Comment: It wasn't clear at all. Do you mind not changing your question all the time? If you have a new question, please ask a new question - asking about how it is generated is a **completely** separate question from the existence of one. Adding such follow-on questions invalidated current answers given in good faith and is unfair to those who took the time to answer the original question.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear in the beginning. I try to get access to the reputation changes for all sites to programm an Add-on. I think now it is clear

Comment: Is the `:)` at the end of the total rep line a smiley or an unbalanced parentheses?

Comment: Most certainly an emoticon, @rene

Comment: @rubo77: then why not use the SE API instead? That is what it is there for.

Answer (score 0):

Your user profile contains a list of reputation changes; click on the [*Reputation* tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069083/rubo77?tab=reputation) (I linked to your Stack Overflow account tab). See [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation) for full details on how to read the history.

A detailed blow-by-blow audit (again, *per site*) is available under the `http://siteurl/reputation` page; see [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) for details on what all the numbers mean.

There is no *global* list; you can get a graph on your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1047481/rubo77?tab=reputation), but not individual reputation events. The achievements dialog aggregates information from various sites; if you have gained reputation from more than one site today, then the site icons at the top of the box link to the per-site reputation tabs of your profiles:

[image: link icons]

Comment: that is not the global list. It only shows the changes for one site

Comment: @rubo77: The achievements list shows you reputation per site too.

Comment: @rubo77: the dropdown in the top bar, showing you reputation and badge notifications, is called the achievements list.

Comment: OK I corrected that in my question. couldn't that achievement list then somehow be extracted to a separate site? That would be what I am looking for

Comment: @rubo77: there currently is no such functionality, no. You'd have to make that a feature request.